# Cannot mount USB 3 harddrive

Tags: mount, 12.10, usb-drive

I cannot mount an USB 3 harddrive. When looking at dmesg I got the following error:

```
[   96.463269] usb 3-2.1: >new low-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[   96.485777] usb 3-2.1: >New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c025
[   96.485787] usb 3-2.1: >New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[   96.485792] usb 3-2.1: >Product: USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse
[   96.485797] usb 3-2.1: >Manufacturer: B16_b_02
[   96.486118] usb 3-2.1: >ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[   96.490149] input: B16_b_02 USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2.1/3-2.1:1.0/input/input12
[   96.490500] hid-generic 0003:046D:C025.0003: >input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [B16_b_02 USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2.1/input0
[  114.088984] usb 3-2.3: >new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[  114.105041] usb 3-2.3: >New USB device found, idVendor=13fd, idProduct=1618
[  114.105051] usb 3-2.3: >New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[  257.531777] usb 3-2.3: >USB disconnect, device number 11
[  258.513912] usb 3-2.4: >new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[  258.514046] usb 3-2.4: >Device not responding to set address.
[  258.717649] usb 3-2.4: >Device not responding to set address.
[  258.921203] usb 3-2.4: >device not accepting address 12, error -71
[  258.937388] hub 3-2:1.0: >unable to enumerate USB device on port 4
```

I have tried to mount the drive on ubuntu-12.04 and it mounts just fine.